# AngularJS migrating 1.5.6 to 1.6 tag name has x- prefix

Tags: angularjs

I’m currently migrating our AngularJS app to 1.6.4 (I know 1.7 is out), but for some reason, now, some of our components have an x- prefix in their tag name. Why does this happen and how do we avoid it?

Comment: It sounds like you've used some kind of tool to assist you with the migration, could you be more specific about your approach? The [official 1.5 to 1.6 migration guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrating-from-1-5-to-1-6) doesn't appear to suggest any changes related to `x-` prefixing of custom elements.

Comment: nope, i just changed my package to 1.6.4 and fixed some issues introduced by auto-binding. it's really weird. And it's only some of my components that get rendered out with the x- prefix

Comment: say i have a component `angular.component("settings", SettingsConfig)` then in the DOM i see `<x-settings></x-settings>`